# How do I get the plain text value for the {{ label }} field in a twig node template?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

Very simply put, I want to print the plain text from the title field of my node without any additional html. Currently I have this in my node--custom-template.html.twig file

```
<h3 class="fancy">
      {{ label }}      
</h3>
```

but it outputs it like this

```
<h3 class="fancy">
          <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/13/title/en/teaser">My Title</span>      
</h3>
```

I'd like it like this

```
<h3 class="fancy">My Title</h3>
```

I've tried using some of the twig filters like |striptags and |raw, but then nothing displays. I'm wondering if there is a template I could edit for this field, or any other way to just get the plain text string of the node title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the unformatted title from the node object:

```
{{ node.label  }}
```

Comment: I also discovered that if you need more control over how the title displays you can use the twig template field--node--title.html.twig - just another option.

Comment: {{ label.0 }} also works in Drupal 9